# How do I fill a html form with fields from my database in Django and postgresql?

Tags: html, django, postgresql, forms

How do I fill a html form with fields from my database in Django and postgresql?

I need to select year from drop down and value of flag(0,1,2), with the combination of these
two I want my form to populate from the values stored previously in the table corresponding to the above combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the data that you want to pass to your html form inside the view and pass the data as context where you render the html file. E.g;

```
def yourview(request):
   data=Data.objects.all()
   return render('yourhtml.html', {'variables':data})
```

Later, inside the html, you can use this 'variables' in your dropdown like below;

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
{% for eachvar in variables %}
  <option value="{{eachvar.id}}">{{eachvar.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
 
</select>
```